# How to use rsynch to update a file remotely by ssh tunnel?

Tags: ubuntu, rsync

I am sending a file around couple of seconds to a remote machine.
However I am trying to use rsynch in ubuntu to synch a file with that remote machine.
But I wan the ssh connection to be open. And synch the file when edited.

Can somebody help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

You should investigate the `lsyncd` tool.

The tool requires a little configuration, but will automatically trigger rsync via ssh every time a file is modified.

For bi-directional synchronization you should look at other tools, such as SyncThing.